# Pushing center div to top of content on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place the `col-md-6` div to the top of my website on mobile, making both of the `col-md-3` elements stack ontop of each other.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="header">
                sidebar 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="header">
                middle
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="header">
                sidebar 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would like a css or js reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `.row` element as `display: flex` (example shows inside a media query but can be done outside the query) then you can use the `order` property to arrange the order of the flex items. Using `flex-direction: column` you can re-arrange the items vertically. You can set an order for all of the items, but a value of `-1` on the single item will assure top placement if the others don't have an order assigned.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    {
    .col-md-6 {
        order: -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need extra CSS for this.** Just use the Bootstrap `order*` classes...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="header">
                    sidebar 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-0">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="header">
                    middle
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="header">
                    sidebar 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/qMj32Mt0Ke